# Understanding Infimum of Countable Cover

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the Exterior Measure section by Stein and Shakarchi (2009).

In their definition an exterior of measure of any subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is

$$m_*(E)=\inf\sum^\infty_{j=1}|Q_j|.$$
where the infimum is taken over all countable coverings $E\subset\bigcup^\infty_{j=1}Q_j$.

*My Question:*

1. Are we taking the infimum of the set of countable coverings first, and then with this infimum, we are summing up the volume of THAT infimum's cubes?
2. Is my understanding of the set of the countable coverings correct? I think of the closed cubes as some sort of cubic box or pillow. So, if we are looking at a collection of cubic pillows that can "cover" the subset $E$, there could be many such coverings. Let us denote this set as $P$. So finding the infimum of $P$ is finding the greatest lower bound of $P$, meaning we are trying to find a set of cubic pillows that just fit into $E$ so that no pillow is outside of $E$ and there is no surplus of space in $E$ extra pillow can squeeze in. Is this correct way of thinking of an infimum of a set?

Reference:
$\textit{Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces}$. Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set $\mathscr{C}$ of countable coverings of $E$ by "cubes", this is a well-defined set, I hope you agree. It will be a very large set in general.

For every such countable covering $C \in \mathscr{C}$ we associate a unique size $s(C)\in [0,+\infty]$, namely $\sum_n |Q_n|$, where we sum over all elements of the cover $C$. Then the set of all possible sizes, formally $S(E):=\{s(C): C \in \mathscr{C}\}$ is a well-defined subset of $[0,+\infty]$ and it has an infimum which we denote $m_\ast(E)$ (as all subsets of $[0,+\infty]$ have a unique infimum).

The infimum is the largest lower bound of $S(E)$, so if $m > m_\ast(E)$, it cannot be a lower bound for $S(E)$ any more (or it would contradict maximality) so there must be some size from $S(E)$ between $m$ and $m_\ast(E)$, so some cover with that size that gives a better approximation for $m_\ast(E)$ than $m$; the infimum need not be attained (it need not be a minimum of $S(E)$, so there is no cover of that *exact* size/value ) but any larger number can always be improved upon by some better approximating one.

So no to 1., you're taking an infimum of *reals* that are associated to covers, it makes no sense to take the infimum of covers in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!